# Difference ubuntu-12.04-alternate-amd64.iso and ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso

Tags: boot, usb-drive, versions

I am trying make a Ubuntu bootable flash drive using the [Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.2.4](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3-/). Also I have downloaded the a file named ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso which is 7.10.956 kb from a torrent from Ubuntu site.

When I open the Universal-USB-Installer. It presents the following screen

[image]

It does not present the option of ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso instead the closest I could find are

1. Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop
2. Ubuntu 12.04 Alternate amd64

Please suggest what option should I choose in the

**Step1: Select a Linux Distribution from the dropdown to put on your USB**
since it does not present the **ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso** iso I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you downloaded the graphic version of the iso (the Live-CD), you should select `Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop` in the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 1):

The Desktop is a Live desktop system and is almost certainly what you want. If your hardware is working you can install from the live CD, and this is what most people do.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

The Alternate CD is a text based CD for installation only. It has a few more options then the desktop CD (LUKS, LVM).

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/amd64/index.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xi-VPj4jzrg

The end installed system is the same.